# Detection of pattern in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

The file I am working with looks like this (only the last two lines are shown):

```
[16]((((((((((648:0.0167313,(((839:0.00281972,903:
[62](((909:0.00419522,895:0.00419522):0.004454hgip: 76898
```

In bash, how could I check whether the last line contains the string `hgip` - and if it does, replace the last line after the [] with the expression from the line above that (the penultimate line) like this:

```
[16]((((((((((648:0.0167313,(((839:0.00281972,903:
[62]((((((((((648:0.0167313,(((839:0.00281972,903:
```

So the number should be retained from the original but the rest of the line copied from the penultimate line. The numeric at the beginning of the line is not always two characters long but could be any length. After the braces there is always a `(`.....

Comment: sorry that is not true..read the q and f of the sita pleasde

Answer (score 2):

Like:

```
sed -n '/hgip/{s/].*/]/;G;s/\n//g};p;{s/\[[0-9]*\]//;x}'
```

Comment: so could you maybe add the {} that i can accpet the answer?

Comment: Nah, you can accpept it as-is :)

Comment: what do you mean..it would be good if it just checks the last lien of the file..the files is really long so it will be a time improbvment..please provide the complete code...

Comment: znd how would I fee d the file to it?

Answer (score 0):

Beauty of sed

```
sed '$!h; ${/hgip/{x; s/.*\]//; x; s/\(^.*\]\).*/\1/; G; s/\n//  }}' file
```

Comment: :) yes, but mine only checks string in last line

Comment: that dies not work...with my tets file i still get the hgip in the lat line

Comment: my place it works. are you sure that you exactly copy/pasted solution line?

Comment: to create output file you should redirect like this sed '.......' <inputfile >outputfile, or dangerously using sed -i which is inplace editing

Comment: Yep yours only check the last line :)

Comment: both solution works, mine  only checks last line, other checks for string in every line